# Using swipe in FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, swipe, fragment-tab-host

I have implemented FragmentTabHost in my app and I wanted to use basic Swipe option for the app to make it look interactive. And I have no idea about that implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) inside your FragmentTabHost
2. Set an adapter to your created ViewPager defined at inner FragmentTabHost.
3. Add [setOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) into ViewPager that can change fragment on onPageSelected() at every swipe .

You can go through this complete [example](https://github.com/Intelliabb/android/tree/master/FragmentHostViewPager).

Comment: Can u give me a full detailed example because this ViewPage Concept is difficult for me to understand? And Is there any simpler way which doesn't involve ViewPager.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Your Example and it worked perfectly But The same fragment Get Repeated Over and Over in all the tabs @QuokMoon

Comment: @qwertygamer it's a different question can you please post this in different thread ?

Comment: Sure @QuoMoon i Will

Comment: I can't do the same with the fragment activity as I am viewing it on a tab. It disappears after viewing it once

Comment: It's not different thing for activities or fragment activity .

Comment: It doesn't return the view when the activity is in back from onPause(). I just can view the fragment once and if I switch tabs and come to the same fragment it is blank.

Comment: I resolved the problem with extending the ViewPageAdapter with **`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`**  replacing **`FragmentPagerAdapter`** . It Seams that **`FragmentPagerAdapter`**  returns the view once the **`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`**   returns multiple time.

Comment: Thanks Fort the Help @QuokMoon